# Java Casting inside Optional with filter and map

Tags: java

In Java 8 I use `Optional.of(Foo).filter(FooChild.class::instance).map(FooChild.class::cast)`.
Is there a faster way to do in in Java 9 or newer (oneliner)?

Answer (score 2):

From Java 15 and onwards, you can do the check and the cast in one operation using pattern matching with the instanceof operator. Like this:

```
if (foo instanceof FooChild child) {
  // You can use the child variable here
}
```

Comment: So Optional.of(Foo).filter(FooChild.class::instance) should also work?
Could not test, becourse I just use Java 11

Comment: @Oekel No, that will still return a `Optional<Foo>`. There's no casting done there. You have to use the syntax in my answer to get the check+cast effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the target type (eg: `FooChild.class`), you don't have much leeway:

```
Optional.ofNullable(foo)
        .filter(Foobar.class::instanceOf)
        .map(Foobar.class::cast)
        .ifPresent(foobar -> {...});
```

This certainly works, but if you want a one liner, you could do it yourself:

```
public static <T> void ifInstanceOf(Object t, Class<T> type, Consumer<T> consumer) {
  if (type.isInstanceOf(t)) {
    consumer.accept(type.cast(t));
  }
}
```

And use:

```
ifInstanceOf(obj, Foobar.class, foobar -> {
  ...
});
```

I'm not too knowledgeable on pattern matching and Java 15 as of now, but I don't think this would work with pattern matching.

Comment: Can not see why a Consumer should work here. Becoming a final operator, so can not continue work with that pipe.

Comment: This was my example :) What I meant at the time, is that you will have to do your one code, you don't have much choice here. You could perhaps create a `static method <T> Optional<T> map(Optional<Object> o, Class<T> type) {return o /* the rather long code */)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using Optional.flatMap and Function creator helper method:
`Optional.of(foo).flatMap(instanceOf(FooChild.class))`

```
public static <T1, T2> Function<T1, Optional<T2>> instanceOf(Class<T2> type) {
    return t -> Optional.of(t).filter(type::isInstance).map(type::cast);
    // Or perhaps better:
//  return t -> type.isInstance(t) ? Optional.of(type.cast(t)) : Optional.empty();
}
```